# Le Président Macron a annoncé la tenue d'un "Beauvau de la sécurité". What does it mean?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

The RFI radio commentator explained that Beauvau is a place in Paris where the Ministry of the Interior is located. But I am not clear why it has been mentioned like this.

It seems to mean some special kind of meeting, event or action, but I am confused what kind of action would be named after the Ministry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose is to organize a meeting in some place around a common topic where representatives of the parties involved, including government and worker unions, gather, discuss and reach an agreement.

This name, usually the nickname of a French Ministry (name of the street where its entrance is located), is used to name the agreement.

Well known examples are [Matignon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accords_de_Matignon), Prime Minister, (1936, 1988), Grenelle, Ministère du Travail, (1968, 2007), [Ségur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9gur_de_la_sant%C3%A9), Ministère de la Santé, and the future Beauvau, Ministère de l'Intérieur (Police)...

Grenelle is specially popular, from [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenelle):

> Par antonomase, un **Grenelle** est dans le langage médiatique français — par facilité politique et journalistique, puis par mimétisme — un débat réunissant des représentants du gouvernement et d'associations professionnelles ou d'ONG, portant sur un thème spécifique et visant à légiférer ou à prendre position. La lexicalisation, plus ou moins admise, du terme est le fruit d'une ellipse stylistique : passant progressivement de la dénomination « Les accords de la rue de Grenelle », à « Les accords de Grenelle », puis à « Le Grenelle ».

Some international agreements might also be substantivated the same way, for example, *le Yalta de xxx*. I have found similar occurrences in English, the Yalta of sth.